# 32bit Raster Stretching from 0 to 0

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-pro, export, stretch

I have a raster that I've been trying to export from ArcGIS Pro as a .tif so I can load it into object based image analysis software. The raster loaded from the .gdb displays fine in Arc and is stretched from 33.2413 to -20.05811. I am exporting the raster as 'Right click > Data > Export Raster' and am saving it to a file folder with the tif extension and specifying 32-bit float (as per the original). When pulled into Arc after exporting it stretches from 0 to 0. I then tried 8-bit signed and the resultant raster was stretched from 33 to -128 but the pixel values are not the same as the original raster. I tried changing the stats but nothing seems to display the original raster values when in the tif format.

Does anyone know of another method or how I could go about getting the values to display correctly in the tif?

Comment: CopyRaster https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm should do the job.

Comment: @MichaelStimson That did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: I would experiment with the Environment Settings when doing the Export Raster tool. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/an-overview-of-raster-storage-settings.htm